# Calculating Bloch-Wigner dilogarithm

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, computational-algebra

Is there some tool/calculator (or some tables) for explicitly calculating values of the Bloch-Wigner dilogarithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sage there is a function CDF(x,y).dilog() which computes the classical dilogarithm of x+yi. (And the Bloch-Wigner dilogarithm can be computed from that.)